# pandas: Get the newest record from each group

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, filter, group-by

I have a dataframe that has the following columns:

`region`
`target`
`date`
`info`
`subinfo`

The combination of `'region', 'target', 'info', 'subinfo'` is unique in the dataframe, except when there is an older duplicate, that has the same `'region', 'target', 'info', 'subinfo'`, but different `date`.

I would like to group the dataframe by `'region', 'target', 'info', 'subinfo'` and create new dataframe with only the newest records from each group / delete the records that do not have the newest date per group.

How can i do that? Thank you!

Comment: please refer to guidelines https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example  in posting a question

Answer (score 2):

If you have a data frame like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([
    ['region1', 'target1', datetime.datetime(year=2022, month=5, day=1), 'info1', 'subinfo1'],
    ['region1', 'target1', datetime.datetime(year=2022, month=5, day=2), 'info1', 'subinfo1'],
    ['region1', 'target1', datetime.datetime(year=2022, month=5, day=3), 'info1', 'subinfo1'],
    ['region2', 'target2', datetime.datetime(year=2022, month=5, day=1), 'info2', 'subinfo2'],
    ['region3', 'target3', datetime.datetime(year=2022, month=5, day=2),
], columns=['region', 'target', 'date', 'info', 'subinfo'])
```

Then your desired data frame can be computed using:

```
final = (
    df
    .sort_values('date')
    .drop_duplicates(['region', 'target', 'info', 'subinfo'], keep='last')
    .reset_index(drop=True)
)
```